# Why is this error message coming up?

Tags: r

When I run a regression on a data set:

`ord_reg<- clm(as.factor(Resp)~log10(Dose), data=dataframe, link="probit")`

I get the following error message:

```
Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

What is the reason for this? Note that the titles of the data set being called in the regression are the same as that of the data set (i.e. "Dose" and "Resp").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `summary(dataframe)`, as well as `summary(log10(dataframe$Dose))`.

You may see some NA/NaN reported, possibly because of negative values being given to `log10()`.