# SOLVED- lmer: Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function (arg 1)

Tags: r, nan, na, lme4, inf

I am not very proficient in R and stumbled upon a problem I cannot seem to fix.

I have some data in a dataframe ("trials") from an economic exchange game for which I want to make some predictions. I load the data into `R` via:

```
trials <- read.table("TrialsCG2.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
```

**Example data** via `dput(head(trials,18))` for the first 18 rows, which includes some `Inf`values

```
structure(list(SubjectID = structure(c(86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L
), .Label = c("01HPG", "01IVW", "02BCH", "02BLB", "02LIM", "02LRH", 
"02TBH", "03AAG", "03bss", "04BAR", "04BSR", "05BEH", "05BEL", 
"05FAF", "05KBF", "05rgf", "05SBK", "05ssw", "06ANG", "06HHG", 
"06HSP", "06IEF", "06IMA", "06SBW", "07BDI", "07BRC", "07BUS", 
"07FBU", "07SAA", "08FAV", "08FIF", "08IBA", "08KMM", "08WHH", 
"09HIC", "09kaa", "09KUR", "09OIR", "10GKC", "10IMK", "11IIA", 
"11SEB", "11SSM", "11WBG", "12IAE", "12IDG", "12IMG", "12LNC", 
"12SDM", "12SMS", "12WCO", "13DOR", "13GBR", "13HKA", "13WPA", 
"13ZMS", "13ZRE", "14HBG", "14IMS", "15DMC", "15IHG", "15KTR", 
"15SAC", "15ser", "15wmk", "16BAS", "16BTT", "16SJS", "17fga", 
"17HBV", "17ICK", "17ILJ", "17KRA", "18HAK", "18HSB", "18MMR", 
"19LNC", "20BIP", "20IBM", "20KEK", "20MKS", "21BAP", "21DMW", 
"21FSM", "21HAR", "21MAT", "22BSB", "22LDS", "22lmr", "23ERW", 
"23MSV", "23uls", "24BFM", "24LCF", "24SIC", "25HCA", "25IBG", 
"25SSM", "26DMW", "26emh", "27DGJ", "27IDH", "27WNV", "28BJT", 
"28HAS", "28kmh", "28MBM", "28SGW", "29FCJ", "29GEJ", "29KHF", 
"30BKH", "31BRF", "31LGR", "31LWH"), class = "factor"), lossPercent = c(8.695652174, 
8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 
8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 
8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 8.695652174, 
8.695652174, 8.695652174), Neuro_Score = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Female = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Education = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Age = c(27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L
), Satisfaction = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), LifeEvent = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Ment_Score = c(3.67, 
3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 
3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67, 3.67), MentSelf_Score = c(3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), MentEmot_Score = c(3.25, 
3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 
3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25), MentEqui_Score = c(4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), MentAffect_Score = c(4.67, 
4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 
4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67), LPFS_Score = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), SchemaED_Score = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), SchemaAB_Score = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), SchemaMA_Score = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), SchemaSI = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), SchemaTotal_Score = c(38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L), RejectionTotal_Score = c(8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 
8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 
8.56, 8.56, 8.56, 8.56), UV1_Score = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), UV2_Score = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), UV3_Score = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), UVTotal_Score = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L), currentPartner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Spieler A", 
"Spieler B"), class = "factor"), goodPartner = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    finalBalance = c(10L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    19L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 25L), goodPartnerBalance = c(10L, 
    10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 29L, 29L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 31L), badPartnerBalance = c(12L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 
    22L, 24L, 24L, 24L), investment = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sentBack = c(1L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L), win = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, -2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), round = 1:18, preCrash = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), crash = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), initialBalance = c(10L, 
    10L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 
    22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L), visibiltyBalance = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), postCrash = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), previousSentBack = c(NA, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L), perInvest = c(10, 10, 20, 8.33333333333333, 7.69230769230769, 
    7.14285714285714, 6.66666666666667, 6.25, 11.7647058823529, 
    10.5263157894737, 9.52380952380952, 8.69565217391304, 9.52380952380952, 
    9.09090909090909, 4.34782608695652, 4.34782608695652, 4.34782608695652, 
    4.16666666666667), ReInvestRatio = c(NA, 1, 2, 0.25, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, Inf, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 1, 1, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")    ``
```

`

Now I want to use an `lmer` to predict the player's investment in each round, such as:

```
fit1 <- lmer(log(investment + 0.5)~LPFS_Score+Education+visibiltyBalance+RejectionTotal_Score+(1|SubjectID), subset=preCrash==T)
```

which runs fine.

I am dealing with a multi-round investment game where players send and receive money within each round. I'd like to use the **ratio** of the sum returned one round prior to the investment in a given round as a predictor.
Computing the previously returned money as such:

```
previousSentBack[round == 1] <- NA
previousSentBack[round == 2] <- sentBack[round == 1]
previousSentBack[round == 3] <- sentBack[round==2]
previousSentBack[round == 4] <- sentBack[round==3]
previousSentBack[round == 5] <- sentBack[round==4]
previousSentBack[round == 6] <- sentBack[round==5]
previousSentBack[round == 7] <- sentBack[round==6]
previousSentBack[round == 8] <- sentBack[round==7]
previousSentBack[round == 9] <- sentBack[round==8]
previousSentBack[round == 10] <- sentBack[round==9]
previousSentBack[round == 11] <- sentBack[round==10]
previousSentBack[round == 12] <- sentBack[round==11]
previousSentBack[round == 13] <- sentBack[round==12]
previousSentBack[round == 14] <- sentBack[round==13]
previousSentBack[round == 15] <- sentBack[round==14]
previousSentBack[round == 16] <- sentBack[round==15]
previousSentBack[round == 17] <- sentBack[round==16]
previousSentBack[round == 18] <- sentBack[round==17]

trials$previousSentBack <- previousSentBack
```

works fine as well.

**Now comes the troubling variable**. I compute the ratio as such:

```
ReInvestRatio = trials$ReInvestRatio

ReInvestRatio <- investment/previousSentBack

trials$ReInvestRatio <- ReInvestRatio
```

Using this newly computed variable in my `lmer` above gives me this error:

> Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function (arg 1)

Doing some research on here and google, I have found the `NaN` and `Inf` to be the culprit, however I cannot seem to remove them. It should be noted that I am assuming that `NA` shouldn't be much of a problem for my `lmer` as some other predictors contain `NAs` aswell. I'd prefer to fix the variable without having to replace all `NA/NaN/Inf` with 0. However the replacing seems to be the problem in the first place.

I tried the following code:

```
trials <- do.call(data.frame, lapply(trials,function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x), NA)))
```

and also:

```
is.na(trials$ReInvestRatio) <- sapply(trials$ReInvestRatio, is.infinite)  

is.na(trials$ReInvestRatio) <- sapply(trials$ReInvestRatio, is.nan)
```

Both visibly remove `NaN` and `Inf` from my dataset but they do not seem to do so "internally" as I still get the same error from the `lmer` and e.g. `sum(is.infinite(ReInvestRatio))` still lists several hundred cases.

I have definitly reached the limit of my R-capabilities and would greatly appreciate some help!

Kind regards,
Max

**Fix**

Nothing really mathematical after all:

I was using `attach(trials)` hence why none of my variables in the `lmer` feature any `trials$` preface. I was expecting this to work equally for `ReInvestRatio` but apparently it doesn't. When I put `ReInvestRatio` into `lmer(log(investment +0.5)~ReInvestRatio +(1|SubjectID))` R keeps pulling the values from my originally created variable in the workspace. This one is not (or at least in my case was not ) cleaned of any `Inf` etc. `trials$ReInvestRatio` as in `lmer(log(investment +0.5)~trials$ReInvestRatio +(1|SubjectID))`
works in the model as this seems to target the correct, cleaned `ReInvestRatio` .

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Would it be possible for you to edit your post to include your data, or some sample data that [reproduces] the error? You could copy the console output of `dput(trials)`.

Comment: Hallo xiliam,
thanks for your response! I was both expecting and dreading your request. I'd like to supply you with some data, however ```dput(trials)``` gives an output too large to actually scroll back up to the beginning in the console. It's a 2088 cases dataset. If I could supply you with the data of just a few participants that should be representative though. I tired to ```subset``` ```dput()```but it does not seem to work. If you could point me somewhere I'd greatly appreciate.

Comment: I got it, updated original post.

Comment: If you want to replace Inf with a zero in a single variable, you could so something like: ```trials$ReInvestRatio[is.infinite(trials$ReInvestRatio)] <- 0
```

Comment: You might also look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517939/5456906).

Comment: Hi @xilliam
thanks for your suggestions! I figured it out while trying your code: I am using ```attach(trials)``` hence why none of my variables in the ```lmer``` feature any ```trials$``` preface. I was expecting this to work equally for ```ReInvestRatio``` but apparently it doesn't. When I put ```ReInvestRatio```into ```lmer(log(investment +0.5)~ReInvestRatio +(1|SubjectID))``` it keeps pulling the values from my originally created variable in the workspace. This one is not (or at least in my case was not ) cleaned of any ```Inf```etc. ```trials$ReInvestRatio``` works in the model. Thanks!